# Updating Tkinter Labels using StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a GUI for a super-simple Vending Machine, but I can't get the labels to update after you make a selection using the radiobuttons. Instead, when a radio button is pressed, it sets the labels to the default value, no matter what was selected.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


#Native Functions
def f_Update():

global chocchoice
global price

c = chocchoice
    if c == "m":
        price = 60
        chocprice.set(price)
        chocname.set("You have chosen - Mars")
    if c == "t":
        price = 70
        chocprice.set(price)
        chocname.set("You have chosen - Twix")
    if c == "mw":
        price = 65
        chocprice.set(price)
        chocname.set("You have chosen - Milky Way")
    if c == "s":
        price == 80
        chocprice.set(price)
        chocname.set("You have chosen - Snickers")



root =tk.Tk()


#Let's declare some  variables!
chocchoice = "s"
price = 0
chocprice = StringVar()
chocname = StringVar()
summary = StringVar()


#Actual Code


frame = tk.Frame(root,
             height = 300,
             width = 800)

frame.pack()

L1 = tk.Label(root,
          text = "Please select a chocolate bar:",
          bg = "white")
L1.place(x=10, y=10)

Radiobutton(root,
            text="Mars",
            padx = 10,
            variable = chocchoice,
            value = "m",
            command = f_Update).place(x=10,y=40)
Radiobutton(root,
            text="Twix",
            variable = chocchoice,
            value = "t",
            command = f_Update).place(x=10, y=70)
Radiobutton(root,
            text="Milky Way",
            variable = chocchoice,
            value = "mw",
            command = f_Update).place(x=10, y=100)
Radiobutton(root,
            text="Snickers",
            variable = chocchoice,
            value = "s",
            command = f_Update).place(x=10, y=130)

L2 = tk.Label(root,
              textvariable = chocname ,
              bg = "white")
L2.place(x=350,y=10)

L3 = tk.Label(root,
              textvariable = chocprice,
              bg = "white")
L3.place(x=350,y=40)
```

I've looked through the site, but didn't find anything that solved this issue specifically.

Comment: you have wrong indentions. where is `root.mainloop()` ?

Comment: `variable=` in `Radiobutton` expects `StringVar`, not normal variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chocchoice` has to be `StringVar()`, not normal variable because all `variable=` and `textvariable=` expects `StringVar()`, `IntVar()`, etc.

```
chocchoice = StringVar(value="s")
```

And then you need to use `.get()`

```
c = chocchoice.get()
```

---

BTW: because you don't assign new value to `chocchoice` using `=` then you don't have to use `global chocchoice` in function.

---

**EDIT:** shorter version

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def update():

    c = choc_choice.get()

    if c in products:
        price, name = products[c]
        choc_price.set(price)
        choc_name.set(name)

# --- data ---

products = { # key: [price, name],
    "m": [60, "Mars"],
    "t": [70, "Twix"],
    "mw": [65, "Milky Way"], 
    "s": [80, "Snickers"],
}    

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# variables (have to be after tk.Tk())

choc_choice = tk.StringVar()
choc_name = tk.StringVar(value="- none -")
choc_price = tk.IntVar()
summary = tk.IntVar()

# left side

left_frame = tk.Frame(root)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)

tk.Label(left_frame, text="Please select a chocolate bar:").pack()

for key, val in products.items():
    price, name = val
    tk.Radiobutton(left_frame, text=name, value=key, anchor='w',
            variable=choc_choice, command=update).pack(fill='x')

# right side

right_frame = tk.Frame(root)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='n', padx=5)

tk.Label(right_frame, text="You have chosen:").pack()
tk.Label(right_frame, textvariable=choc_name).pack()
tk.Label(right_frame, textvariable=choc_price).pack()

# start

root.mainloop()
```